# How to add timestamp while redirecting stdout to file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

I have a program (server) and I am looking for a way (script) that will redirect (or better duplicate) all its `stdout` to file and add timestamp for each entry.

I've done some research and the furthest I could get was thanks to [How to add timestamp to STDERR redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507674/how-to-add-timestamp-to-stderr-redirection). It redirects `stdout` but the timestamp added is of the time when the script finishes:

```
#!/bin/bash
./server | ./predate.sh > log.txt
```

code of `predate.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
    echo "$(date): ${line}"
done
```

It seems that server output is flushed after exit of the program.(without redirecting it works fine). Also if I try using `predate.sh` on given example in mentioned thread, it works perfectly. I am aware it would be easy adding a timestamp to the main program but I would rather avoid editing its code.

Comment: So the problem is that all the timestamps are the same and the time when the script finished? Sounds like this is a problem with `server` output not being properly buffered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered might be what you are looking for

Comment: Pipe the output to _awk_.  It provides a function called _strftime_.

Comment: The `expect` distribution comes with a program called [`unbuffer`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html) : `unbuffer ./server | ./predate.sh > log.txt`

Comment: Also see _man stdbuf_.

Comment: What do you get if you try Dennis's solution in the linked question? e.g. `./server.sh > >( ./predate.sh > log.txt )`

Comment: @BroSlow "./server.sh > >( ./predate.sh > log.txt )" does the same - logs with same datetime on every line

Comment: @wondra Any luck when using `unbuffer` as glenn jackman suggested above? (for either solution)

Comment: Both Graeme and denull pointed to right solution, i would select it as correct answer if it were in answers, thanks.
it should be run as "stdbuf -oL ./server | ./predate.sh > log.txt" using unbuffer makes server unable to respond in console to "EXIT" for safe turning off server. (ctrl+c is "nono")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-stdin)

Comment: @umläute can you *please* read the question before marking as duplicate? The problem was identified and answered by an comment years ago(changing stdout buffer settings). If you read it and still think this question need formal answer, feel free to post an answer based on said comment.

Comment: What is happening is, the system detects that you are piping (and not going to terminal), and assumes that any real-time requirements can be relaxed, it then (for performance reasons) buffers the pipe.

Answer (score 56):

I recently needed exactly that: receive log messages in a serial console (picocom), print them to a terminal and to a file AND prepend the date.

What I now use looks s.th. like this:

```
picocom -b 115200 /dev/tty.usbserial-1a122C | awk '{ print strftime("%s: "), $0; fflush(); }' | tee serial.txt
```

- the output of `picocom` is piped to `awk`
- `awk` prepends the date (the `%s` option converts the time to the *Number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC* - or use `%c` for a human-readable format)
- `fflush()` [flushes any buffered output](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) in `awk`
- that is piped to `tee` which diverts it to a file. (you can find some stuff about `tee` [here](http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/2013-12-31-top-10-unix-command-line-utilities-2013.html#tee))

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'd like to add to anyone using this, to print a timestamp similar "2015-11-13 17:04:57:" the pattern is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:".

Comment: Awk, ever to the rescue.

Comment: This is the only output for me: `awk: line 2: function strftime never defined`

Comment: @ygoe, what version of awk are you using?

Comment: @mwfearnley GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Comment: maybe install gawk first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684212/using-strftime-function-in-mawk

Comment: You can also add `tee -a`, so that tee appends to the file, if this is the behavior you would like to have.

Comment: How to add millis?

Answer (score 32):

**moreutils `ts`**

Absolute date and time is the default:

```
$ sudo apt-get install moreutils
$ (echo a;sleep 1;echo b;sleep 3;echo c;sleep 2;echo d;sleep 1) | ts | tee myfile
$ cat myfile
Apr 13 03:10:44 a
Apr 13 03:10:45 b
Apr 13 03:10:48 c
Apr 13 03:10:50 d
```

or counting from program start with `ts -s`:

```
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts -s
00:00:00 a
00:00:01 b
00:00:04 c
00:00:06 d
```

or deltas between two consecutive lines for benchmarking with `ts -i`:

```
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts -i
00:00:00 a
00:00:01 b
00:00:03 c
00:00:02 d
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts -i '%.s'
0.000010 a
0.983308 b
3.001129 c
2.001120 d
```

See also: [How to monitor for how much time each line of stdout was the last output line in Bash for benchmarking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797246/how-to-monitor-for-how-much-time-each-line-of-stdout-was-the-last-output-line-in/49797547#49797547)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, moreutils 0.60.

Answer (score 10):

For Me Your Code is working perfectly fine

Check this is what I tried

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  echo "hello"
done
```

predate.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo $(date) ":" $line;    
done
```

then

```
./test.sh  | ./predate.sh
```

gives me

```
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
Tue Jan 14 17:49:47 IST 2014 : hello
```

This can be redirected to some file using ">"  or ">>" for append

[image: Check Snapshot]

Comment: If you read my question carefully - this works. Stdout of script wroked for me but stdout of program did not(strange). I needed stdout of program. The issue is more complicated then simply redirecting output - output of program was fushed at once after it ended.

Comment: Formatting is lost: I struggled to get formatting correct and ended up with this `function predate () { tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 -I{} echo "$(date) : {}"; }` (Note this still does not answer the question).

Answer (score 1):

Again, using `ts` from `moreutils`, you can just use exec at the top of your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(ts>>file.log)

echo hello 1
echo hello 2
sleep 5
echo hello 3
```

Answer (score -3):

If I understand your problem is to have stderr output included in your log.txt file. Right ?
If that's what you want the solution is:

./server 2>&1 | ./predate.sh > log.txt

Regards

Comment: Maybe your server is executed too quickly... Try to print nanoseconds as follows and check the difference: echo "$(date +%T.%N): ${line}"

Comment: I have function for turning off server which take 25 second, believe me - I would notice...

Comment: Of course but your server may print some lines very quickly and stop printing anything until it ends up... Add a begin and end message to your predate.sh script.